# Call a control using the Name property

Tags: vb.net

I have a series of controls: TextBox, Label and Panel. There controls are created dynamically in the code not the designer. My problem is that How can I call The Label and The Panel control using the .Name property that I set in the code?
This is what I have

```
Public Class frmMain
  Private Sub DraControls()
    Dim pans as New Panel
      With pans
      .AutoSize = True
      .Parent = Me
      .Name = "Panel1"
      End With
    Dim labs as New Label
      With labs
        .Text = "%"
        .Name = "PercentageLabel00"
        .Parent = pans
      End With
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then I have a click event that will make the label change its Text.

```
Dim PercentTextLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("PercentageLabel00"), Label)
PercentTextLabel.Text = "OK"
```

I need to change the text of the Label and I am getting an Error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I already treid other approaches like `Controls.Find` but I got the same results

Thanks!

Comment: The first code snippet never actually adds the controls you create to the `Controls` collection of the form. If you don't put them in, how can you get them out? If you do put them in that collection then the second snippet will work, assuming that you use the correct name. Of course, if you put them into the `Controls` collection of some other container, e.g. a `GroupBox` or `TabPage`, then you'd have to get them out of that `Controls` collection again, not the `Controls` collection of the form.

Comment: @jmcilhinney isn't the function .Parent puts them in the controls collection?

Comment: Yeah, I was just posting that I realised that was the case. The thing is, as I said, you are adding the `Label` to the `Controls` collection of the `Panel`, not the form, so you can't get it back from the form later. You can get the `Panel` from the `Controls` collection of the form but then you must get the `Label` from the `Controls` collection of the `Panel`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i tried getting the Panel the from the Form (SUCCESS) but when I go down to get the Label from the Panel, i get the null reference exception.

Comment: For the record setting the `Parent` property isn't enough (it's also not necessary). To add the label to the panel you need to call `pans.Controls.Add(labs)`. As for accessing it, make sure to specify `True` as the second parameter of [`Controls.Find(String, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) in order to perform a recursive search through the entire form and all its containers. This returns an array so you'd have to access the first element: `Me.Controls.Find("PercentageLabel00", True)(0)`.

Comment: @Ajax after you've found the panel, do you then look in the panel's control collection for the label? This version of your sample code works for me:             `Dim panel As Panel = CType(Me.Controls("Panel1"), Panel)
            Dim PercentTextLabel As Label = CType(panel.Controls("PercentageLabel00"), Label)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As Panel = CType(Me.Controls("Panel1"), Panel)
    CType(p.Controls("PercentageLabel00"), Label).Text = "OK"
End Sub
```

Or in a single line

```
CType(CType(Me.Controls("Panel1"), Panel).Controls("PercentageLabel00"), Label).Text = "OK"
```